# I have a piece of java code but it is running error now. Hope everybody help please

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("20/04/2022", "20/04/2022","20/04/2022","21/04/2022", "22/04/2022", "22/04/2022"));
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1000","1000","1000", "15000", "36000", "36000"));

      
        for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++) {
            while ((list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1))) && (list2.get(i).equals(list2.get(i + 1)))) {
                list.remove(i);
                list2.remove(i);
                
            }
        }
        for (String alist : list) {
            System.out.println("list1: "+alist);
        }
        for (String alist2 : list2) {
            System.out.println("list2: "+alist2);
        }

    }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSpeK.jpg)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSqA3.jpg)

Comment: Believe the error message: "out of bounds".

Comment: Because you are trying to access `list.get(i + 1)` you need to stop your loop 1 value earlier than `list.size() - 1`. So change your condition to `i < list.size() - 2`

Comment: What is this piece of code trying to do? I find that `while` loop suspicious.

Comment: By the way, assuming you're trying to remove duplicates, if you remove elements inside of the inner `while` loop, the boundaries you started the `for` loop with won't be valid anymore, so you'll find yourself with an `i` that could very well be out of bounds.

Comment: A better approach would be, instead of removing elements directly, to have two additional lists where you put elements only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break from the while loop, if the last item removed causes your `i+1` to be out of bounds.
Try this:

```
   for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++) {
        while ((list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1))) && (list2.get(i).equals(list2.get(i + 1)))) {
            list.remove(i);
            list2.remove(i);
            if(i+1 >= list.size() || i+1 >= list2.size()) break;
        }
   }
```

As gapserg has mentioned in his answer, you modify your initial list as a side effect. This would still work for your approach, but there are better alternatives.

For example, you can create a new list to copy unique pairs instead of having to delete all duplicates as stated in the comments.

Side note: Your approach only works, if the lists have the same size, if all duplicates are next to each other and if you don't care that your initial lists get modified.

Answer (score 0):

It's not idea using loop "for", because you change your "List".

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5}));
    int i = 0;
    while (i < list.size() - 1) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1))) {
            list.remove(i);
        } else i++;
    }
    System.out.println(list.toString());
```